How to retrieve SUMO results from VEINs?
I'm currently working on a project that integrates SUMO with OMNeT++ using Veins. I am running different simulation scenarios by changing the TraCIScenarioManager penetration rate variable in the omnetpp.ini file.
Now that I'm changing this PR, my understanding is that not all vehicles are being simulated in OMNET++, only connected ones. I am able to retrieve different information about the connected vehicles through traci functions in VEINS, however, my problem is that I can't retrieve any information about the vehicles that are not connected (ie, vehicles only simulated in SUMO and not in OMNET++).
I can only get pre-defined outputs from SUMO such as ones defined in the router.xml file (SSM device, fcd-out...etc). However, I can't retrieve any custom information that I would usually get using a python script that uses TRACI functions for SUMO.
Is there any way to retrieve this information about non-connected vehicles?

As far as I know the current Veins setup connects itself as a traci client and does not allow multiple traci connections. You could try to work around this by adapting the connect mechanism as mentioned in the SUMO documentation.
But personally I think you might be better off generating all the data you need with output files and post-processing them. But this of course heavily depends on your use case.

I did realize that the easiest (but probably most inefficient) is to generate data using one of SUMO's output functions (I'm using emissions output). It's not the best solution (as these files tend to be very large) but it works for now to post-process the results about all vehicles.
